# Unable to find symbol in shared object

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, shared-objects

I am having two shared objects: A.so and B.so
A.so contains definition to function add_check_2a

From my main function in main.c, I invoke a function add() in B.so using dlsym.
This function add() needs to call the function add_check_2a which is defined in A.so

A.c :

int add_check_2a( int a, int b){

return (a+b);

}

In B.c file, I have defined something like this:

extern int add_check_2a(int a, int b);

int add(){

return add_check_2a(10,5);

}

I am counting on linux LAZY binding to automatically bind the function call to the symbol in A.so.

In  main , I have opened both these shared objects during initialization.

main.c:

dlopen(A.so, RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);

dlopen(B.so, RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);

Then I find symbol add in B.so using dlsym and call the function using function pointer.

I dont want to do another dlopen in B.c and want the linker to somehow do lazy binding.

Any suggestions?

RGds
Sapan

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution myself. It was pretty simple.

We should just open the .so using RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW flag in dlopen.

Not deleting this question so that this information can be of any help for others